# When did the <input> tag come about, and in what web browser?

Tags: technology, computers

I realize that the <isindex> tag came first, but which browser was the first to support the <input> tag and when?

Comment: Hmm. It is really a "History of Computing" question. Considering that many *history.se* members are also participants in the computing stack exchanges, I think this question is reasonable if odd. Since answering it may require digging through reams of old RFC spec releases, I wouldn't consider it trivial but possibly too hard to answer?

Comment: I saw the question through meta review pane which didn't show the answers. Apparently it is easy to answer :-)

Comment: Should we move this question to "Programming?" SE. It's technically history, but a specialized topic that might be better answered by others in this specialty.

Comment: I agree with @LateralFractal.  We see a lot of questions on Academia.se that have mostly to do with computing but since there's so much crossover they usually get answered.

Answer (score 9):

The `<input>` tag is a part of HTML forms, which first appeared in the Mosaic browser in [April 1993](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/book4/ch02.html). It was standardized in [HTML2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1866) in November 1995.

Answer (score 0):

The input tag is part of HTML and as such not an "add on" that just one browser would have used/supported. According to [this page](http://www.martinrinehart.com/frontend-engineering/engineers/html/html-tag-history.html), the input tag was a part of HTML2, which rolled out between 1995 and 1997. That would put it on Netscape Navigator and IE (IE 3 came out in 1996).